# intent recognition using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, android-intent

I have this simple intent.json file

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi",
        "How are you",
        "Is anyone there?",
        "Hello",
        "Good day"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hello"
      ],
      "context_set": ""
    },
    {
      "tag": "goodbye",
      "patterns": [
        "Bye",
        "not interested",
        "Goodbye"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "ok bye"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "thanks",
      "patterns": [
        "Thanks",
        "Thank you"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "My pleasure"
      ]

    },
    {
      "tag": "greetiing_exchange",
      "patterns": [
        "What about you",
        "you",
        "how about your self"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "i am perfect, thanks for asking"
      ],
      "context_set": ""
    }
  ]
}

from fuzzywuzzy import process

    for intent in intents['intents']:
        Ratios = process.extract(message,intent['patterns'])
        for ratio in Ratios:
            highest_value = max(Ratios, key = lambda i : i[1])
            print(highest_value)
```

Now i want input from user identify the pattern and output response.

The problem is it is not iterating through every pattern when i input "hi". Its output is
('Hi', 100)
('not interested', 45)
('Thanks', 45)
('What about you', 45)

I want the pattern which is higher in range of 80 to 100, and print response from that pattern

Another thing there is a library Rhasspy which can be used for intent recognition how can i use that library for this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `process.extractOne` and `score_cutoff` parameter:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import operator

ratios = []
for idx, intent in enumerate(intents['intents']):
    # ratio = process.extractOne(message, intent['patterns'], score_cutoff=80)
    # if ratio:
    # --- New in python 3.8: walrus operator ---
    if ratio := process.extractOne(message, intent['patterns'], score_cutoff=80):
        ratios.append((idx, ratio[0], ratio[1]))

responses = intents['intents'] \
                   [max(ratios, key=operator.itemgetter(2))[0]] \
                   ['responses'] if ratios else []
```

```
>>> responses
['Hello']
```

Comment: Every thing is working fine here thank you for that but instead printing response from json it is just matching with patterns and prints closest pattern. How can i change that ?? like when it sees a pattern it shows relevant response, i tried adding loop and changing some stuff here and there but couldn't figure out

Comment: You want the highest ratio of each `tag`?

Comment: No i want highest ratio from each pattern  and which ever pattern have highest ratio, it shows response from that pattern like if i type "bye" its in second tag's pattern when it sees  that it reaches to it response and print that response which is "ok bye"

Comment: I hadn't seen the key `responses` :-P

Comment: "tag": "goodbye",
      "patterns": [
        "Bye",
        "not interested",
        "Goodbye"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "ok bye"
      ] here like this

Comment: There can be more than one response? (`responses` is a list)

Comment: yes there could be more than one responses like for each pattern there is a different response, i have posted intent.json file above

Comment: And if your asking that each pattern can have more than one response than yes for that too like "responses": [ "ok bye", "bye", "tc" ]

Comment: @malic92. At the end, is it what you expected?

Comment: yeah, sorry about late reply but you fixed it thank you :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it fits your need. It's important to others to indicate the problem is solved and the solution is right for a similar case.